# Services not started during boot

Tags: 10.04

Ubuntu 10.04.4
server/no gui

The computer is hanging somewhere during the boot.  I am never presented with a login prompt on tty1.

I *can* hit Alt+F2 and login (or ssh in) and everything seems fine, but none of my services have been started (e.g., apache2).  Alt+F1 is a blank screen.  I can start the services manually.   Nothing in the logs jumps out at me, but perhaps I'm not looking in the right spot.

Here is the entire boot.log:

```
fsck from util-linux-ng 2.17.2 
fsck from util-linux-ng 2.17.2
/dev/sda1: clean, 142934/11714560 files, 12045212/46848768 blocks
/dev/sdb1: recovering journal /dev/sdb1: clean, 12620/61054976 files, 4555959/244190000 blocks 
init: ureadahead-other main process (1064)
terminated with status 4  
  * Starting AppArmor profiles               [ OK ]
  * Setting sensors limits                   [ OK ]
```

I have 3 available kernels from the grub boot menu and all have the same issue.  I booted the latest (2.6.32-39-server) --verbose, and nothing jumped out at me.

Can anyone tell me where I should be looking or have any theories?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find the cause of the problem.  Re-installed.